# guess the missing letters in sequence

Tags: letter-sequence

Guess number 16 in this sequence:

1. WS
2. EL
3. JRC
4. AA
5. ME
6. MB
7. VS
8. MT
9. TP
10. BS
11. BF
12. AK
13. GK
14. VK
15. VA
16. ??

Comment: let me know if the question needs to be improved. I am very new here.

Comment: Is it possible that any other tags could apply to your puzzle??

Comment: I will take a look at tags, but I afraid it may spoil the puzzle

Comment: Oh, then don't worry, Just though that if we narrowed it down a bit it would be easier.

Comment: I added a hint.

Comment: @WOEITG I think the hint is not really helpful. I would remove it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The next letters are

> MC, for [Magnus Carlsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_Carlsen), most recent [World Chess Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship)

Here's a breakdown just to show that the others on the list work:

> 1. Wilhelm Steinitz
>  2. Emanuel Lasker
>  3. José Raúl Capablanca
>  4. Alexander Alekhine
>  5. Max Euwe
>  6. Mikhail Botvinnik
>  7. Vasily Smyslov
>  8. Mikhail Tal
>  9. Tigran Petrosian
>  10. Boris Spassky
>  11. Bobby Fischer
>  12. Anatoly Karpov
>  13. Garry Kasparov
>  14. Vladimir Kramnik
>  15. Viswanathan Anand
>  16. Magnus Carlsen

Comment: brilliant ! how did you find it !?!

Comment: I figured they were probably people's initials, and I looked here: peoplebyinitials.com for a few that seemed "unusual" enough to narrow something down. I was a tiny bit surprised to find that GK helped narrow it down better than VK or VA.

Comment: There really is a web site for everything these days, isn't there?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I was as surprised to find out it existed as you are!